# issue with my update-query

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to submit an update function, but for some reason it's not working and I can't figure out why... Someone who does?

**UPDATE SQL-SYNTAX:**

```
public function updateProject($db, $id) {
       $sql = "UPDATE tblProject SET 
        name = '".$db->escape($this->name)."',
        photo1 = '".$db->escape($this->photo1)."'
        WHERE id = '".$id."'";
       return $db->insert($sql);
 }
```

**INSERT FUNCTION:**

```
public function insert($sql) {
    mysql_query($sql, $this->_connection);
    return mysql_affected_rows($this->_connection);
}
```

**PHP:**

```
$project = new Project();
$project->name     = $_POST['newproject_name'];
$project->photo1    = $_FILES['images']['name'][0];

if($project->updateProject($_DB, $projectname)) {
    $feedback = "OK!";
} else {
    $feedback = "NOT OK!!";
}
```

And in case you were wondering, `$project->name` and `$project->photo1` are filled in correctly.
Any ideas? I hope I gave you everything you need, if not, let me know!

**EDIT 1**: I used the 2 first answers, but no results. Yet...
**EDIT 2**: I also don't get anything from `$feedback`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a stray opening parenthesis after the SET keyword. Remove it.

```
public function updateProject($db, $id) {
       $sql = "UPDATE tblProject SET 
        name = '".$db->escape($this->name)."',
        photo1 = '".$db->escape($this->photo1)."'
        WHERE id = '".$id."'";
       return $db->insert($sql);
 }
```

Comment: it's sometimes the smallest things that gets even the best programmers..lol

Answer (score 1):

```
public function updateProject($db, $id)
```

requires 2 parameters being passed but when you do

```
if($project->updateProject($_DB))
```

you're only passing 1??

Comment: where are you setting your $id?

Comment: in your function updateProject you are telling it to update where the id = $id...the $id is it loaded somewhere?? and if so how are you passing it to that function cause obviously it's not in if($project->updateProject) line...

Comment: Yes I pass the `$id` in the line `$project->updateProject($_DB, $projectname))`

Comment: if $projectname is integer then remove the single quotes WHERE id = ".$id.";

Comment: Thanks for the hit, but I think the answer of Joe was the one I was looking for! Thanks anyway for thinking along!

Answer (score 1):

Your `updateProject` needs two variables and the second one is missing in your call, resulting in an invalid query.

**Edit:** Based on your edit; I'm guessing `$id` needs to be an integer or a string, you are passing an object.

Exactly what row do you want to update? I don't see anything in your php code that defines the ID of the row you want to modify, you are just generating a new object, not getting one from a database for example.

Comment: Ok, the `$project` was a copy/paste mistake. Now it's corrected. In the code that isn't in the post, I fill in a form with data from my database and then I update it...

Comment: @Michiel Is `$projectname` the same as `$project->name`? If it is, the `id` in your query should be `name` as well, or the other way around.

Comment: No `$projectname` is an integer given in somewhere else in the code

Comment: Got it! I think it was the answer of Joe! Thanks anyway for thinking along!